# NSRegularExpression (iOS)

Tags: ios, nsstring, html-parsing, nsregularexpression, nsstringencoding

A have a little problem with parsing HTML into string. I have a big string and I need delete characters between "script" tag. Something like this :

```
    <script...>Some text here</script>
```

So I need to delete "Some text here". I think it would be great to use NSRegularExpression. Can anybody help me ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you will generally be advised to not parse HTML with regular expressions (see [my all-time favorite S.O. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1271826)), you can approximate it with something like:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<script.*?>(.*?)</script>"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                                                         error:&error];

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                         NSLog(@"%@", [string substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:1]]);
                     }];
```